# Resolving error in Svelte project despite functional application

Tags: svelte

I recently initiated a new project using Svelte, and I encountered an error that appears in the console. Interestingly, the project still functions as expected despite this error. I'm seeking assistance to understand and resolve this issue.

Here's the code of the error:

```
import './app.css'
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
  target: document.getElementById('app'),
})

export default app
```

And the error:

> Cannot find module './App.svelte' or its corresponding type
> declarations.

Could anyone please provide insights on what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

I tried changing the name of the file, reinstall it and the command "npm audit fix", but all these attempts did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Do not screenshot code, it's inaccessible. Just copy it as text and point out where the error occurs and what the error was. Code if formatted via ``` blocks.